# How do I reference an instance of a class using its tag?

Tags: iphone

I have several instances of a UIControl class Foo being instantiated, one instance corresponding to each cell in a UITableView.  The Class has:

```
BOOL selected;
UIImageView *imageView;
UIImage *imageOne;
UIImage *imageTwo;
```

I've assigned each instance a tag:

```
foo.tag = indexPath.row;
```

I would now like to reference the UIImageView.image for a (or several) specific instance(s) by its tag to switch it to the other image.

In my search I've seen things like classes being assigned tags using initWithTag (I assume they're assigning tags)...

```
SomeClass *someClass = [[SomeClass alloc]initWithTag:1 ...

[someArray addObject: [[SomeClass alloc]initWithTag:2 ...
[someArray addObject: [[SomeClass alloc]initWithTag:3 ...
```

...but I haven't seen how they are later referenced by that tag.

I have seen a reference to getChildByTag which had promise, but I can't find it in the documentation or examples (maybe not iphone).

Does anyone know how reference the imageView.image within an instance using the instance's tag? (the imageView doesn't have a tag)

Thanks

---

Let me be a bit more specific.  As each instance of Foo is set up in the UITableViewCells I use addTarget

```
[self addTarget: self action: @selector(switchImage:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Then I have this method to switch the images:

```
- (void) switchImage:(id)sender
{
    selected = !selected;
    imageView.image = (selected ? imageOne : imageTwo); 

    // self.tag in here is the indexPath.row from the foo.tag initially assigned
    // NSLog(@"switchImage:%@",sender);

}
```

This works perfectly.  I click on the image and the image switches.  But in the entire tableView, I only want 1 imageOne all the rest to be imageTwo so I want a way to first turn off all images and then turn on the one.  I therefore felt that I could to loop thru all of the instances of Foo using the tag to either somehow directly change the imageView.image or run switchImage in each of the instances to turn off each cell's image.

Lastly, when I look at sender via NSLog, I see that each Foo has a different address so I was wondering if something like allTargets (Foo is a UIControl) would allow me to get to all of the switchImage methods.

I'm pretty deep into this rabbit hole but I'll certainly start over if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that there are other ways to deal with this, but you could add all your Foo objects to an array or set and iterate through them until you find the one with the tag you want, then access the imageview in the usual way.

Comment: Please see my answer below with more details.  I was trying to keep it simple but I think the additional details are necessary for clarification.  Thanks.

Comment: I stick by my suggestion. Add each Foo object to an array (if you could index by the tag it would save some work) and iterate through the array, calling switchImage for each object. You can test for the tag of each object and not change (or double change? I'm not entirely clear on your setup below) the one you want. It's just not possible to access an object directly by its tag in the way you wish.

Comment: I'm starting to agree with your approach.  I was just doing some reading to see how exactly to do this, but what I've read thus far is starting to feel like a solution.  I'm sure I'll figure it out but any reference or any more specifics would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Works perfectly.  Put the imageView in an array and just looped thru to turn them off.  Thank you.  More than just a solution, you gave me the rest of the weekend to have fun.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm getting you right, you try to access `Foo` objects (globally) by the tag you assigned to them before. There's no way to do that and it's not what the `tag` property of `UIView`s was designed for.

You have to use another way to access your Foo objects. There are uncountable ways of setting up a way to access objects. Since you would usually access them from their data source or view controller, I’d add a dictionary with there. You could also use `UITableView`'s `visibleCells` property to only change images on cells that are actually displayed.

Comment: Please see my answer below with more details.  I was trying to keep it simple but I think the additional details are necessary for clarification.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I feel a bit lost, but how about [`[UIView viewWithTag:]`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/viewWithTag:)?

Comment: I know I can assign a tag to the imageView and I'm working on doing that but that's not as easy assigning a tag to the instance of the class which is what I have done, so I need a way to get to the imageView via it's class's tag.

Answer (score 0):

UIView instances have a tag property.  You can access them from their superview using:

```
UIView *view = [superview viewWithTag:n];
```

Comment: I know I can assign a tag to the imageView and I'm working on doing that but that's not as easy assigning a tag to the instance of the class which is what I have done, so I need a way to get to the imageView via it's class's tag, but let me see if this will work and if so I'll try harder assigning the imageView tag.  Thanks.